# ungzip the data in nodejs

Tags: node.js, zlib, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I am trying to ungzip the base64 decoded buffer object using the code below, but the callback function is not getting executed. Can someone tell me what i am missing here

```
function (event, context) {
    event.Records.forEach(function (record) {
        // Kinesis data is base64 encoded so decode here
        var payload = new Buffer(record.kinesis.data, 'base64');
        zlib.gunzip(payload, function (err, data) {
                console.log("new data2");
            if (!err) {
                console.log("new data3");
                console.log(data);
            }
            else {
                console.log("new data4");
                console.log(err, err.stack);
            }
        });
    });
    context.done();
};
```

Comment: Is it at least taking the error path?  What is getting printed?

Comment: It's not... The output is blank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the `context.done()` call into your callback so that the Lambda function isn't terminated early. Like this:

```
function (event, context) {
    event.Records.forEach(function (record) {
        // Kinesis data is base64 encoded so decode here
        var payload = new Buffer(record.kinesis.data, 'base64');
        zlib.gunzip(payload, function (err, data) {
            console.log("new data2");
            if (!err) {
                console.log("new data3");
                console.log(data);
            }
            else {
                console.log("new data4");
                console.log(err, err.stack);
            }
            context.done();
        });
    });
};
```